# Find a triangle in a graph using an algorithm with a specific run time

Tags: algorithm, graph, runtime, big-o, notation

I need to find an algorithm that finds triangular cycles in an undirected graph. The runtime of the algorithm should be n^2,81

I really do not know how I can achieve this. Would be great if anyone could help!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen Finding and Counting Given Length Cycles by N. Alon, R. Yuster, and U. Zwick? https://m.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/ayz97.pdf (Algorithmica (1997) 17:209-223)

Comment: No, but thank you I will give it a read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you search is **matrix multiplication**.
Multiply adjacency matrix with itself three times and search for non zero entrees in the main diagonal.
matrix multiplication is O(N^2.81):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm

**EDIT:**

Recall that in the ith row of the adjacency matrix there will be '1' for each vertex connected to i, the same goes for the column.

When you multiply the matrix with itself, (M^2)ij = sum (Mik*Mkj). in other words (M^2)ij is the number of 2-edge paths from i to j.

Now if you multiply again to get M^3, in every cell (M^3)ij there will be the number of 3-edge paths from i to j. so in the main diagonal (M^3)ii there will be the number of 3-edge paths from i to i, a triangle.

Comment: Nice answer - but I will elaborate more about the solution (even simple coding example)

Comment: Interesting! I thought it would have something to do with Strassen's Algorithm, but I am not sure how to use it to find out the the solution to my problem. I think I don't have the background knowledge to combine matrices with paths.

How exactly would I turn a path into a matrix?

Comment: @shuki avraham 

So if I have the graph 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 for example, I would have the adjacency matrix

0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0

I would multiply the matrix three times using Strassen to save on runtime costs. Then by the final matrix I would add the diagonals to find out how many triangles are formed. Wouldn't the number be much too high?

- Obviously my example does not include triangles ;) Would I divide the sum of diagonals by 6 to consider that I am counting all edges and paths in both directions?


Is this correct so far?

Comment: @JenniferWagner Yes, every triangle is counted 6 times, so you need to divide by 6. Note that this method won't give you the list of the triangles, just the number. The number of the triangles can be as much as O(n^3) so listing them can't be done faster.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I need to figure out if a graph contains at least one triangle, so the runtime of n^2,81 can be achieved, correct?

Comment: @JenniferWagner Correct.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use a modified version of the [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm. Try to think the simple graph you can have, a triangle. Start from any vertex with BFS and stores who is the parent node and the distance from the root.
Whenever you encounter an already visited (but not finished vertex), that you can simple color gray, you have to check the distance and the parent.

```
   B     Start BFS from A: node A has dist=0, parent=Null
  / \                      node B has dist=1, parent=A
 /   \                     node C has dist=1, parent=A
A - - C
```

For example you are now on C, B his already visited and A is finished (Black), now you check the adjacent of C, you see B and check if the distance is the same and if you have the same parent, if true you have found a triangle, if not you encountered a cycle but not a triangle.

This will be better than `O(n^2)`
The complexity of this algorithm (BFS) is the number of vertex + the number of edges: `O(|V| + |E|)`.

Comment: This will not work. Your method will only find triangle if two of its edges are in the bfs tree. There can be a triangle with two of its edges not in the tree. consider the graph: {(1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,5), (3,6), (5,6)}. its bfs tree is {(1,2), (1,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,6)}. The only triangle in the graph (3,5,6) will not be found.

Comment: @shukiavraham Thank you for your answer, do you think there is an alternative way of the one you post it? (the matrix multiplication)

Comment: You can get `O(E*max(deg(v)))` which is better if the number of edges or the max degree is limited. for each `edge (u,v)` go over the adjacency list of `v` and search for vertex `w` s.t. there is an `edge (w,u)`.